# How pthread_mutex is initialized in global scope when does not call pthread_mutex_init()

Tags: c

I'm studing about thinking philosopy's problem using mutex var.
Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void *func(int n);
pthread_t philosopher[5];
pthread_mutex_t chopstick[5];

int main()
{
     int i;
     void *msg;
     for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
          pthread_mutex_init(&chopstick[i],NULL);
     }
     for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
          pthread_create(&philosopher[i],NULL,(void *)func,(int *)i);
     }
     for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
          pthread_join(philosopher[i],&msg);
     }
     printf("
");
      for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
      {
          pthread_mutex_destroy(&chopstick[i]);
      }
     return 0;
}

void *func(int n)
{
     printf ("
Philosopher %d is thinking ",n);
     printf("
Philosopher %d is in the dining room ", n);
     pthread_mutex_lock(&chopstick[n]);
        sleep(3);
     pthread_mutex_lock(&chopstick[(n+1)%5]);
        printf ("
Philosopher %d is eating ",n);
        sleep(2);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&chopstick[n]);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&chopstick[(n+1)%5]);
     printf ("
Philosopher %d finished eating ",n);
}
```

In this code, I declare global mutex array var.

`pthread_mutex_t chopstick[5];`

but in main function, does not initialize `chopstick[0]`.

In this case, what happens in `chopstick[0]` mutex reference?

And It can be possible to initialize `chopstick[5]`?
`pthread_mutex_init(&chopstick[5],NULL);`

Comment: Array indexes start at 0 and end at `n-1` where `n` is the number of elements in the array. So the indexes for an array of 5 elements are 0 to 4. In other words, all of the loops in `main` should be `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Comment: Yea. I think so too. so When I get this code, I think it is definitly wrong code. but I compile and run this code, it works well!

Comment: "*what happens in chopstick[0] mutex reference*". It is Undefined Behaviour. You must init the mutex to a valid value before using it. The [pthread_mutex_init manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) tells you ways to do it.

Comment: "*but I compile and run this code, it works well!*". That is the nature of Undefined Behaviour in C. When you have bugs that cause UB the behaviour is unpredictable. It can crash, it can produce wrong values, it can even appear to "work" or any other unpredictable behaviour. And it can change any time. Don't rely on that always working.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: *"but in main function, does not initialize chopstick[0]."* - that same `main` function also never *uses* `chopstick[0]` *anywhere*, but that is neither here no there. Instead, it incorrectly indexes both `philosopher` and `chopstick` from `1` through `5` rather than `0` through `4`, thereby invoking *undefined behavior*.  Fix *all* of the invalid indexing in this code and it makes your question moot.

Comment: Okay. In summary, That code is incorrect but it can be compiled but it works. And we call this "undefined behavior". Thanks.